# Update Tier Price Using "Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')"

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello I tried to update tier_price of products using Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action') but it not works.

My code is as below:

```
    $model = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->getResource();
    $attrData = array();
    $attr = "tier_price";
    $tierPrices = array(
                        array('customer_group_id' => '0', 'website' => '0', 'qty' => '50', 'price' => '9.90')
                  );

    $attrData[$attr] = $tierPrices;
    $model->updateAttributes(product_id, $attrData, $store_id);
```

Comment: Put your code in try.....catch block and debug which error you are facing, and put tha error description here.

Comment: It not gives any exception or error.

Comment: Have you check that you pass proper data in product_id and store_id.

Comment: yes , i tried it by putting static value for test. But not works. Have you tried above code in your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to used this code to set product tier_price.

```
try 
{
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $tierPrices[] = array(
             'website_id'  => 0,
             'cust_group'  => 1,
             'price_qty'   => 50,
             'price'       => 9.90
    );
    $product_id = 2;    //PASS YOUR PRODUCT ID HERE   
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
    $product->save(); 

    echo "Price Save Sucessfully";


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Note :** I test above code in my local machine, and it working fine. I create one test file in magento root and try above code.

Comment: I know this solution. But it takes much time to save product. Thats why i was trying to use Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action') model for save tier price.

Comment: Take much time is another things, I think your goal is to save tier_price, So i post answer here.

Comment: Please read my Question Title Again. SO you will get idea what i want to do. Thanks for your effort.